# issue with legend boxes in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

we are using Chartjs for some graphs and having an issue with cliackable legend boxes, as they are being displayed in some cases and not displayed in other cases as in the below snapshots :

[image: With legend boxes]

[image: without legend boxes]

The case that we have observed for displaying these boxes is when the page auto refreshes while it is minimized.

Can anyone please let us know what is wrong here?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the fact that your canvas isn't big enough to fit your legend at small enough sizes.

One solution would be to create a custom legend that is completely separate from the canvas. This can be done using the legendcallback function.
e.g

```
legendCallback: function (chartInstance) {
    //Generate legend here
}
```

Also, make sure that you have

```
responsive: true
```

set in your chart options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but both graphs are being drawn in the same canvas with the same size, and also when the auto refresh happens and the browser is minimized those legends come up.